# In what ways can a PC gain advantage on Wisdom checks other than being a Wildhunt Shifter?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, rogue, ability-scores, advantage-and-disadvantage

I am making an Inquisitive Rogue and since it depends a lot on the Wisdom Score for its main abilities, I was thinking of using the Wildhunt Shifter's shifting ability to gain advantage on Wisdom checks would be very helpful. But I am not choosing the Eberron race so I ask for your help to find if there is any other way to improve my Wisdom rolls by using spells, feats, items or some other method.

> **Shifting Feature.** While shifted, you have advantage on Wisdom checks. [...]

TL;DR: Is there a way to replicate the Wildhunt Shifter shifting ability from Eberron by using items or spells?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Magic items

- **Sentinel Shield**

  > While holding this shield, you have **advantage on** initiative rolls and **Wisdom (Perception) checks**.
- **Ring of Truth Telling**

  > While wearing this ring, you have **advantage on Wisdom (Insight) checks** to determine whether someone is lying to you.
- **Eyes of the Eagle**

  > While wearing them, you have **advantage on Wisdom (Perception) checks** that rely on sight.
- **Robe of Eyes**

  > The robe lets you see in all directions, and you have **advantage on Wisdom (Perception) checks** that rely on sight.
- **Rod of Alertness**

  > While holding the rod, you have **advantage on Wisdom (Perception) checks** and on rolls for initiative.
- **Sword of Zariel**

  > While holding the sword, you gain **advantage on all Wisdom (Insight) checks**.
- **Cursed Luckstone**

  > While carrying the stone, you can gain **advantage on ability check** of your choice.
- **Blackrazor**

  > As long as these temporary hit points last and you keep Blackrazor in hand, you have **advantage** **on** attack rolls, saving throws, and **ability checks**.

Answer (score 3):

**Feats**

*Dungeon Delver* gives advantage on Wisdom (Perception) checks to find secret doors.

*Lucky* gives you an extra die on attack rolls, ability checks, or saving throws three times a day.

*Magic Initiate* would give you access to the *Guidance* cantrip (see below).

**Spells**

*Enhance Ability: Owl's Wisdom* (2nd level) will give you advantage on Wisdom checks for one hour. It is on the Bard, Cleric, Druid, and Sorcerer spell lists. You'll need a level dip to get it.

*Guidance* (cantrip) doesn't give advantage, but it does provide +1d4 to ability checks. It is on the Cleric and Druid spell lists. This could be picked up with the *Magic Initiate* feat.

Comment: Dungeon Delver would not help an Inquisitive Rogue with any of it's particular subclass features.

Comment: Probably overkill, but the ninth level spell Foresight grants advantage on practically every d20 roll, including Wisdom saving throws.